# Multiple markers on google map from state variable React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Im new to react and building an app to better understand it. Im currently using the Google maps api to render a map and want to render multiple markers to the map.

Im having to use a geocode api to get the lat and longitude for each of my locations so I can display them on the map as markers. Currently my code isn't displaying anything to the screen and I think its because the map is trying to render the markers with an empty state variable before the fetch calls are completed.

I have tried to search for an answer but cant find anything that is similar to what Im trying to do.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api"
import Settings from "../Settings"
import mapSyles from "./MapStyles"
import { LogContext } from '../divelog/DiveLogProvider';

export const MapRender =(props) => {
    const {diveLogs} = useContext(LogContext)
    const [latLong, setLatLong] = useState()
    

    //get the logs location and run that through api to get lat and long
    useEffect(()=>{
     
        let latLongs = []
        diveLogs.map(dl =>{
            return fetch(`http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward?access_key=MYKEY&query=${dl.location}&limit=1
            `)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(parsedRes => {
                    latLongs.push(parsedRes.data[0])
                  })


        })
        setLatLong(latLongs)
        console.log(latLong) 
    },[diveLogs])

    
    

    //here I want to map through the state variable and display all of the markers on the map



    
    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMap
                mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
                options={options}
                zoom={1}
                center={center}
            >
                
                {
                    //this is where I map through the state variable
                    latLong.map(l =>(
                     <Marker key={l.lat}
                         position ={{lat: l.latitude, lng: l.longitude}} 
                         />
                    ))
                }
            </GoogleMap>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update the state right inside your response . like this

```
diveLogs.map(dl =>{
            return fetch(`http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward?access_key=MYKEY&query=${dl.location}&limit=1
            `)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(parsedRes => {
                    setLatLong( prevLatLongs => [...prevLatLongs ,parsedRes.data[0]] )
                    
                  })


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need update the state when the fetch result is ready:

```
useEffect(()=>{
     diveLogs.map(dl =>{
        return fetch(`http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward?access_key=MYKEY&query=${dl.location}&limit=1
        `)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(parsedRes => {
                setLatLong((prev)=> [...prev, parsedRes.data[0]])
              })


    })
},[diveLogs])
```

Comment: I tried this and ended up getting a bunch of errors and an empty array when trying to console log my state variable